# Alternative structures for "not only ... but also ..."?

Tags: conjunctions, phrasing

I'm trying to write this essay and I find myself writing too many "not only ... but also ..." structures. Can you guys help me come up with some alternatives?

Basically, I want this kind of **progressive** effect:

> Doing this is not only fun, but also one of the most important activities of human beings.

How about this one:

> He is not only a teacher, but also one of the greatest educators in history.

Comment: As Cerberus already noticed, it should be "one of the greatest educators."

Comment: What do you mean with "progressive effect"?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14462/what-defines-a-correlative

Comment: Progressive effect is like when you say one thing first, but what you really want to emphasize is the thing come after it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Doing this isn't exclusively fun, it's one of the most important activities of human beings.

> Doing this is not purely fun, on the contrary, it's one of the most important activities of human beings.

> Doing this is not wholly classified as fun, conversely it's one of the most important activities of human beings.

> He is not a mere teacher, he is one of the greatest educators in history.

> He is a teacher and more, one of the greatest educators in history.

Comment: The sentences seem run-on sentences.

Comment: I think so too. Especially the third one, even kind of amusing.

Comment: Added more to my amusing-ness

Comment: But this is not what is asked. "Not only" implies "part of" and here examples antagonize/estrange "fun" with/from "activities of human beings"

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a [correlative conjunction](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/correlaconhterm.htm).

> A paired conjunction (such as not only . . . but also) that links balanced words, phrases, and clauses.
>
> The elements connected by correlative conjunctions are usually parallel--that is, similar in length and grammatical form.

You can find a link to a list of other kinds of correlative conjunctions above.

And you can find how to deal with the problems these create here: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/parallelism.htm#correlative

Comment: And can you apply these know-hows to phrases from question?

Answer (score 1):

> Doing this is fun, but also one of the most important activities of human beings.
>   Doing this is fun, and one of the most important activities of human beings.
>   He is not just a teacher; he is one of the greatest educators in history.
>   He is not a mere teacher: he is one of the greatest educators in history.

Between the first two sentences I wrote there is a little difference in meaning, though.

Comment: @Cerberus: That is true; I merely copied the sentence as written by the OP.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought (happens to me too sometimes).