# Poetic syntax with "as" and "so"

Tags: conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, complex-sentences, correlative-conjunctions

Does anyone know how to describe the type of poetic syntax of the line:

> "As the deer panteth for the water / So my soul longeth after thee" or something to that effect.

I'm not sure if this would be an example of parataxis or hypotaxis.

Normally, "so" is a coordinating conjunction, which makes me think that this might count as parataxis, but the adverb "as" seems to make the first clause dependent and thus render the syntax as hypotaxis.

Another related question: is as/so a correlative conjunction like neither/nor or either/or?

Comment: Apparently, [the critic Stanley Fish has written that the difference between parataxis and hypotaxis is like “the difference between walking through a museum and stopping as long as you like at each picture, and being hurried along by a guide who wants you to see what you’re looking at as a stage in a developmental arc she is eager to trace for you.”](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/08/07/parataxis-and-hypotaxis/). What's the question again?

Comment: [As ye sow, so shall ye reap](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/as-ye-sow-so-shall-ye-reap). Again, *what's the question?*

Comment: *As* is a subordinating conjunction, so it is hypotaxis. As to the name of this construction, I'm not sure there is any. Its just a subordinate clause with *as* followed by a main clause introduced by *so*, which is an adverb here. Perhaps it is the slight redundancy of *so* that makes it appear poetic; without *so*, it is a common construction: `[just] as he had predicted, [so] the Trojans welcomed the great horse.` The conjunction / relative adverb *as* refers forward to the adverb *so*, which is often left out in ordinary English; then *as* could be said to refer to the entire main clause.

Comment: @Cerberus: C'mon. _As_ `X` _so_ `Y` is a correlative quantifier -- an equative in this case. It's a graph showing a consistent positive slope for `X`/`Y` from zero up.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I hadn't thought of that, but, now that you mention it, I have never heard a convincing argument why *correlative* is a syntactically meaningful category. See my answer here: [What defines a correlative?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14462/what-defines-a-correlative) I'd love to hear you arguments why it *is* important/useful.

Comment: @Cerberus: Correlative simply means that one variable correlates with another. It can be positive or negative, but it's a two-dimensional graph in any case. There has to be **some** way to specify the variables for a graph, after all.

Comment: @JohnLawler: And how do you define "correlate" syntactically? Or is this really something semantic, as in the ordinary mathematical/statistical sense of the word? Normally people mean something syntactic by *correlative* in descriptions of language, and it includes pairs like *not only...but also...*, which do not correlate in the mathematical semantic sense. I am sensing different senses of the word here...arg!

Comment: So sentences that use correlative quantifiers would automatically be hypotactic, no?  Thanks for such an interesting discussion of syntax... I find this really fascinating. @JohnLawler

Comment: @Cerberus: it's more mathematical. If `x` increases when `y` increases, it's correlation. There are other tests, but that's close enough for jazz or language. Oh, and why shouldn't you sense different senses of the words? Has something changed?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Okay, so bottom line, the mathematical definition we all know is what you mean, and the syntactic term as used in school books is entirely unrelated.

Comment: I know nothing of syntactic terms as used in school books, nor what their relations are. School books vary like television programs, and provide an equally valid and nuanced view of reality.

Comment: Some other thoughts: a comparative/superlative with an adverbial clause? Perhaps not quite comparative in the most formal sense. Definitely correlative, but if that's not specific enough in itself, what about a simile? ...Just some other descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this would be hypotaxis, because of its *as this, so that* form, where the clauses each depend upon each other. In this case, as/so would be correlative.